# Laravel middleware cannot read posted data

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

Is it possible to read PUT, POST data in custom middleware?

This does not work:

```
$request->input('phone_number');
```

I'm trying to check posted data (check if customer_key or user_key is present) from a mobile app before reaching it to controller

Comment: did you tried `$request->phone_number;`

Comment: That should definitely work.. are you registering your middleware only on those method types or on the whole resource? So it gets `null` when you are trying a GET method type?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @skdroid, `$request->phone_number` works. 
The problem for me was I was using POSTMAN and sending `PUT` request using `form-data`.
I switch it to `raw` with `JSON` and it works.